# sql Teradata difference in months

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I need to get the difference between dates, but I just need to get the whole months that have passed. So for example between "1990-05-24" and "1990-05-27" it should say 0. It would also be 0 for "1990-05-02" and "1990-05-29" because the month has not finished.

I already got the difference in months using MONTHS_BETWEEN(), but I get months with decimals, and ROUNDing is not an option since sometimes it should be up and sometimes down.

I thought about setting al dates to day 01. In both colums Closing_date and Opening_date. But can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: The easiest way is to truncate using `cast(months_between(..) as int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to count *boundaries* between months.  If so, you can use `months_between()` after truncating to the first of the month:

```
months_between(trunc(date1, 'MON'), trunc(date2, 'MON')
```